# After saving entity bundle, entity_get_info('node') missing 'token type' property

Tags: 7, entities, tokens

After saving any entity bundle, e.g. node type on `admin/structure/types/manage/node-type` page, node 'token type' is gone:

```
$info = entity_get_info('node');
// isset($info['token type'])) == FALSE
```

After I change common.inc to regenerate entity info like this

```
if (FALSE && $cache = cache_get("entity_info:$langcode")) {
  $entity_info = $cache->data;
}
```

it started to work as expected.

Only 'node' entity type is affected.

In order to fix this I had to patch `entity_get_info`:

```
   $entity_info = &$drupal_static_fast['entity_info'];

+  if (!empty($entity_info) && !isset($entity_info['node']['token type'])) {
+    $entity_info = NULL;
+  }
+
   // hook_entity_info() includes translated strings, so each language is cached
   // separately.
   $langcode = $language->language;
@@ -7857,7 +7861,7 @@ function entity_get_info($entity_type = NULL) {
     if ($cache = cache_get("entity_info:$langcode")) {
       $entity_info = $cache->data;
     }
-    else {
+    if (empty($entity_info) || !isset($entity_info['node']['token type'])) {
       $entity_info = module_invoke_all('entity_info');
```

What can be the root cause of this issue and how can it be fixed?

I searched for an answer and found several similar questions on Drupal.org, but the only recommended thing is to clear cache several times (which does not even help in my case).

Comment: Have you tried to run cron, and then clear the cache? Other suggestions say that updating token and running drush rr after that works.

Comment: I wish this would never happen again, so need to find the root cause.

Comment: What version of token module are you using? And core version?

Comment: The latest stable versions of core and contrib modules. Token 7.x-1.7. And Entity API 7.x-1.9, which includes entity_token

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is but I think its a known bug, there's a huge thread on Drupal.org about this issue, https://www.drupal.org/project/token/issues/1265848#comment-11424803

Comment: Did you try to update drupal core?

Comment: I have Drupal 7.67, the most recent version

Comment: @Jdrupal thanks for the link, maybe my problem is related to memcached (https://www.drupal.org/project/token/issues/1265848#comment-12341744)

Comment: Cool, there might be a lot of helpful comments on that.